# Spring security entry point and AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: spring-security

Im trying to use an alternative login site for authenticating access to my other running spring-security, creating a single sign on.

However, i am not able to initially redirect to this alternative site when connecting to my application.

I have my applicationContext.xml specified like this:

```xml
<http entry-point-ref="testProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
                default-target-url="/home"
                always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="testProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="com.test.TESTAuthFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginUrl" value="https://example/login.cgi"/>
    <beans:property name="startUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
    <beans:property name="otherParams" ref="otherParams"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="otherParams" class="com.test.OtherParams">
    <beans:property name="pemFile" value="/data/test.pem"/>
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="testCookie"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.test.TESTAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="" /> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <beans:property name="otherParams" ref="otherParams"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Basically my authenticationProcessingFilter makes use of a class defined as:

```java
public class TESTAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter  {
```

And my testProcessingFilterEntryPoint makes use of a class defined as:

```java
public class TESTAuthFilterEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, InitializingBean {
```

What is suppose to happen is that i should be redirected to an external site, get authenticated and process the information generated from this login by looking at the generated cookie. Lastly just verify that a portion of this information correlates to some other information kept in a database.

However, when i start this, i get no errors, nothing. It just starts and leaves me at the standard login screen for spring-security. I cant get the initial redirect to kick in. It does not even enter the  method within the TESTAuthFilterEntryPoint

```java
@Override
commence(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse....)
```

Just as a side comment, it does not even trigger any difference when doing it like a minimalistic case e.g :

```xml
<http>
    <http-basic/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="kass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Still going to the standard core login screen.

Comment: As always, the output from the debug log is the best place to start in finding a solution. If you can post that for the request which you expect to be redirected, then it should clearly show how it is handled.